# How to enable jQuery UI in JSFiddle?

Tags: jquery-ui, jsfiddle

There is no option for jQuery UI in the "Frameworks & Extensions" part. Should i add it as an external resource?

Comment: The option does exist (as a checkbox under "Frameworks & Extensions"), but its availability depends on the version of jQuery you selected.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried it with jQuery 2.1.3, and it didn't work. With jQuery (edge), it works perfectly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The UI for adding JS frameworks has been adapted (multiple times).

Currently you can **add these frameworks by clicking on the settings-cog-wheel of the Javascript section**:

[image: screenshot of JS context menu]

Comment: Thanks :) I knew that this list appears somehow, but I couldn't find out how.

Comment: Is `Frameworks & Extensions` removed? I can't find it.

Comment: It has been moved to the "cog" in the Java Script pane

Comment: Two things to note in 2019: (1) The interface now looks different from the screenshot above. In the JavaScript pane, the heading you need to click will initially say, "JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)." The cog button has been replaced with a downward-pointing triangle. (2) As noted by other posters, if you select "jQuery (edge)" or "jQuery 1.9.1" from the Frameworks & Extensions drop-down menu, controls for adding jQuery UI will appear. However, if you select any other version of jQuery (2.x.x, 3.x.x), jQuerui UI will NOT appear as an option.

Answer (score 17):

The JSFiddle Frameworks & Extensions selection has been moved to the **Javascript pane options!**

[image]

Answer (score 17):

### New Answer

Checking the jsFiddle site today, I see they added some controls.  This is in the same style of answer as reto's and dotancohen's.

I have not tested the UI portion specifically yet, but I do notice that when you select jQuery versions `(edge)` or `1.9.1`, jQuery UI is available in the list of checkboxes that appear beneath the dropdown box.

[image: Selected Language JavaScript, Frameworks & Extensions jQuery (edge), and checked the jQuery UI 1.12.1 box.]

### Old Answer

Along with the other answers (I intend to complement [dotancohen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299774/1091943)) discussing that pretty significant JSFiddle UI change, I wanted to finish the information by saying jQuery UI specifically was not an option for me.  I had to go into "External Resources" on the left-hand side and enter these URLs as well:

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js`
`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`

[Example jQuery UI JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pysis/chux7pev/)

Answer (score 5):

Under External Resources > click the text field and enter the url for a hosted jQuery library such as this one from google: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js`. Then click the plus icon.