# How to make an HTML button trigger a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

The JSFiddle I am working with: https://jsfiddle.net/mL0uLx81/1/

I've been trying to trigger a function called `toggleCheckbox` on the click of a button.

I've tried it by doing `onclick="toggleCheckbox()"` on the `input` tag, and I've tried by adding `document.getElementById("surveyButton").addEventListener("click", toggleCheckbox, false);` to the JS file. Neither of them have worked, and I am unsure why.

Comment: Your code works for me on JSFiddle, just put an `alert()` in the function code and you'll see it.

Comment: You didn't include jQuery in your fiddle. Did you check the developer console for errors? And since you're using jQuery, `document.getElementById("surveyButton").addEventListener("click", toggleCheckbox, false);` could be reduced to `$('#surveyButton').click('toggleCheckbox')`

Comment: Can you post your complete code so we can help you.

Comment: In your JSFiddle you are using jquery without including it
Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932542/how-to-enable-jquery-ui-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: Also `toggleCheckbox()` is wrapped in onload handler function, it's not defined in the global scope, hence the inline listener won't find the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close, just a couple of fixes.

First, you're not including jQuery in your JS fiddle.
Secondly, your `toggleCheckbox` function is not in the global scope, so it can't be accessed inline.
Lastly, you'd need to update your appear/disappear functions.  It seemed like they weren't toggling both the checkbox and the button in the same way.

## Updated Code

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" />
<input type="button" value="Open" id="surveyButton" /> <!--removed inline JS-->
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleCheckbox() { //moved function to global scope, if you wanted to add the listner inline you'd do it this way.

  if($("#toggle").is(':checked')) {
    SurveyAppear();
  }  else {
    SurveyDisappear();
  }
}

var SurveyAppear = function() {
  $("#surveyButton").prop('value', 'Open'); //switched from Close
  $("#toggle").prop('checked', false); //changed to false
}

var SurveyDisappear = function() {
  $("#surveyButton").prop('value', 'Close'); //switched from Open
  $("#toggle").prop('checked', true);
}

document.getElementById("surveyButton").addEventListener("click", toggleCheckbox, false);
```

See it working in the updated fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/mL0uLx81/2/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please find below plunker link
https://plnkr.co/edit/vYvi4F45s6PpKrRvwqsA?p=preview

There might be spelling mistakes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input onclick="sampleFun()" type="button" value="button"/>
  </body>
</html>

// Code goes here
function sampleFun() {
  alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSFiddle you are using jquery without including it in the fiddle itself. An `alert();` would work but nothing with `$`

**There were other mistakes corrected below** like @AdamKonieska noted

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932542/how-to-enable-jquery-ui-in-jsfiddle)[image: instructions]

Your NEW HTML (removed onclick):

```
<input type="button" value="Open" id="surveyButton" />
```

Your NEW JS (changed true for false in `$("#toggle").prop('checked', false);`):

```
var toggleCheckbox = function() {

  if ($("#toggle").is(':checked')) {
    SurveyDisappear();
  } else {
    SurveyAppear();
  }
}

var SurveyAppear = function() {
  $("#surveyButton").prop('value', 'Close');
  $("#toggle").prop('checked', true);
}

var SurveyDisappear = function() {
  $("#surveyButton").prop('value', 'Open');
  $("#toggle").prop('checked', false);
}

document.getElementById("surveyButton").addEventListener("click", toggleCheckbox, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can select the input tag that specifies the button, and attach a `.click()` listener to it, like this:

```
$('[type=submit]').click(function() {
     toggleCheckbox();
});
```

Otherwise, I think you have done the right thing. Hope my above solution helps!